# Dependencies by flavor or build type using androidTestUtil

Tags: android, testing, gradle

Is it possible to have dependencies by flavor or build type using `androidTestUtil`?

I'm using test-butler and using this line to get the apk onto the device before tests run:

```
androidTestUtil 'com.linkedin.testbutler:test-butler-app:1.3.1@apk'
```

However I want to be able to run tests on a physical device without test-butler, without having to modify my gradle file when I'm testing.

The solution provided by this question [dependencies by flavor in android studio build.gradle file, is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569125/dependencies-by-flavor-in-android-studio-build-gradle-file-is-it-possible) doesn't really work with this androidTestUtil, I'm wondering if there is another way?

With the flavor `releaseTest`:

`releaseTestandroidTestUtil 'com.linkedin.testbutler:test-butler-app:1.3.1@apk'`